# MongoDB Data API ArrayFilter function is missing ( Mongodb REST API )

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was trying to use the REST API to update a specific element in the object array Mongodb.
Using their Data API

As per their documentation
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api-resources/#update-a-single-document

The ArrayFilter function in the SDK is missing here. How to archive this using REST API ?

Comment: What do you mean by **ArrayFilter function**?

Comment: You can't it's just not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature of `arrayFilters` is not supported in data-api, Vote for the feature request if it is really helpful for you,

https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/945334-atlas-app-services/suggestions/45629674-support-identifier-with-arrayfilters-feature

---

The alternative approach is to create a [custom HTTP endpoint](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/data-api/custom-endpoints/), design your request, and execute an update query in a function.